# python regular expression: match either one of several regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and three patterns that I want to match and I use the python `re` package. Specifically, if one of the pattern is found, output "Dislikes", otherwise, output "Likes". Brief info about the three patterns:

> pattern 1: check if all character in string is uppercase letter
>
> pattern 2: check if consecutive character are the same, for example,
>   `AA`, `BB`...
>
> pattern3 : check if pattern `XYXY` exist, `X` and `Y` can be same and
>   letters in this pattern do not need to be next to each other.

When I write the pattern separately, the program runs as expected. But when I combine the 3 patterns using alternation `|`, the result is wrong. I have check the stackoverflow post, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613831/merge-several-regular-expressions-into-one-re) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613091/regular-expression-match-either-of-two-conditions). Solution provided there do not work for me.

Here is the original code that works fine:

```
import sys
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pattern1 = re.compile(r"[^A-Z]+")
    pattern2 = re.compile(r"([A-Z])\1")
    pattern3 = re.compile(r"([A-Z])[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\1[A-Z]*\2")

    word = sys.stdin.readline()
    word = word.rstrip('\n')
    if pattern1.search(word) or pattern2.search(word) or pattern3.search(word):
        print("Dislikes")
    else:
        print("Likes")
```

If I combine the 3 pattern to one using the following code, something is wrong:

```
import sys
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pattern = r"([A-Z])[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\1[A-Z]*\2|([A-Z])\1|[^A-Z]+"

    word = sys.stdin.readline()

    word = word.rstrip('\n')
    if re.search(word, pattern):
        print("Dislikes")
    else:
       print("Likes")
```

If we call the 3 patterns `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`, I also tried the following combination:

```
pattern = r"(p1|p2|p3)"
pattern = r"(p1)|(p2)|(p3)"
```

But they also do not work as expected. What is the correct to combine them?

#### Test cases:

- "Likes": `ABC`, `ABCD`, `A`, `ABCBA`
- "Dislikes": `ABBC` (pattern2), `THETXH`(pattern3), `ABACADA`(pattern3), `AbCD`(pattern1)

Comment: post updated with some examples

Comment: because it includes a pattern `THTH`, I have said in post that "letters in pattern do not need to be next to each other" for pattern 3.

Comment: it has `AAAA`, I have also said "X and Y can be the same"  for pattern 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153628/discussion-between-jdhao-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a single pattern that joins yours:

```
([^A-Z]+|([A-Z])\2|([A-Z])[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\3[A-Z]*\4)
```

So, why does it work?

It consists of a simple `(p1|p2|p3)` pattern, where `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are those you defined before:

```
[^A-Z]+
([A-Z])\1
([A-Z])[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\1[A-Z]*\2
```

It can be decomposed as:

```
(
  [^A-Z]+
 |([A-Z])\2
 |([A-Z])[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\3[A-Z]*\
)
```

The problem you were encoutering is the numbering of the groups.

First off, when you combine `p2` and `p3`, both refer to `\1`, but the latter represents different things across the two patterns.
Therefore, `p3` should become `...\2...\3`, since there is an additional group before.

Furthermore, the group indices refered to by `\number` are indexed in the order in which they are opened.
As a consequence, the very first parenthesis, corresponding to the opening of the outer `(...|...|...)`, is counted as the first group, and `\1` will refer to it.
Of course, this is not what you want.
But in addition, this gives you an error, because then, `\1` refers to a group that has not been closed yet, and thus not defined.

Therefore, the indices should be shifted by one, becoming `\2`, `\3` and `\4`.

Such `A|B` regexes are usually nested into parentheses, but the outer ones could actually be dropped, and the indices shifted back by one:

```
[^A-Z]+|([A-Z])\1|([A-Z])[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\2[A-Z]*\3
```

---

Here is a small demonstration of this pattern:

```
import sys
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pattern1 = re.compile(r"[^A-Z]+")
    pattern2 = re.compile(r"([A-Z])\1")
    pattern3 = re.compile(r"([A-Z])[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\1[A-Z]*\2")    
    pattern = re.compile(r"([^A-Z]+|([A-Z])\2|([A-Z])[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\3[A-Z]*\4)")

    while True:
        try:
            word = input("> ")
            print(pattern1.search(word))
            print(pattern2.search(word))
            print(pattern3.search(word))
            print(pattern.search(word))
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
```

Interactive session:

```
> ABC    # Matches no pattern
None
None
None
None

> ABCBA  # Matches no pattern
None
None
None
None

> ABBC   # Matches p2
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='BB'> # p2 is matched
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='BB'> # Jointure gives the same match

> ABACADA # Matches p3
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='ABACADA'> # p3 is matched
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='ABACADA'> # Jointure gives the same match
```

Comment: Is the outer parentheses in `(p1|p2|p3)` a must?

Comment: @jdhao It seems it's not, but it's the usual regex syntax. You don't need them here, but if you were to embed this regex into a larger, you certainly would need them.